# Howto ABRecordRef + image larger than 320x320 px?

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, contacts, abrecordref

I'm working with Address Book Framework internally and I'd like to know if it's possible to use an image bigger than 320x320 px in the `ABRecordRef` opaque type.

I tried to set an image from mainBundle but I was not lucky because when reading the image again, the `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat` function sends me always an image with the same size (320x320).

**Is there a way to keep a larger image in ABRecordRef?**

Comment: Maybe linking a Core Data object with the person/image could be it?

Comment: That's my first solution, but I'd like to know if it's possible with de framework, thanks!